# PayPal donation description shows broken characters when entering hebrew

Tags: wordpress, utf-8, paypal

I have a donations form in my `WordPress` blog and the `Donation Description` is in Hebrew. Now in the `PayPal` site the `Donation Description` is in gibberish.

How do i fix it? I have tried to encode the page in `UTF-8` and `UTF-8 without BOM` and still nothing.

Comment: What encoding is your Wordpress page in?

Comment: which page? the template? `utf-8`

Comment: Did you try to save ALL template files / pages / PLUGINS in UTF-8 without BOM ? (especially the plugins handeling paypal somehow )

Comment: Are you 100% sure the page where the text is entered is set to UTF-8 in the browser in the "Encoding" menu? Just to make sure. And can you show an example of the gibberish?

Comment: yes i am sure, and no i haven't tried encoding all of my site files to utf-8. the gibberish is `׳×׳¨׳•׳ ׳׳׳•׳¡׳“ ׳’׳ ׳–׳™ ׳©׳׳¢׳•׳` and its not on my site. its in `PayPal`, where it says `Purpose`

Comment: if you press the `Donate` button here `http://www.gshimon.co.il/%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9D-%D7%9B%D7%A2%D7%AA/` you will see the gibberish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be that PayPal is expecting ISO-8859-1 data by default.

Try this from their [manual](https://cms.paypal.com/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_formbasics):

> Setting the Character Set – `charset`
> Use the charset HTML variable to specify the character set and character encoding for the billing information/log-in page on the PayPal website. In addition, this variable sets the same values for information that you send to PayPal in your HTML button code.
>
> For example, the following INPUT tag sets the encoding to UTF-8:
>
> ```
> <INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8">
> ```